# Android run time exeption on resuem

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle, onresume, extras

Good day ALL

I am trying to create a program that shows toast message onResume however the app crashes before starting and I couldn't figure out how to fix it.
the link provided as if my question is duplicated does not even help me to fix this.
however I've changed my code based on that question and the same error happen

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn ;
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityTwo.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    String vlue=new String();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    if(b.getString("val")!=null){
        vlue = b.getString("val");
    }
    String comp="false";
    if(vlue==comp){
        Toast.makeText(this,"The subactivity finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**Logcat stack**

12-09 02:27:16.460 4808-4808/com.example.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/lib/x86
12-09 02:27:17.146 4808-4808/com.example.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/lib/x86
12-09 02:27:17.353 4808-4808/com.example.myapplication W/art: Verification of java.lang.Object com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.access$super(com.example.myapplication.MainActivity, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) took 150.015ms
12-09 02:27:17.403 4808-4808/com.example.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-09 02:27:17.488 4808-4808/com.example.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
**12-09 02:27:17.488 4808-4808/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 4808
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6312)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)**

This the second class

```
public class ActivityTwo extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
    Button btn ,finish;
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    finish=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });}




public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    String name="false";
    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("vla", name);
    startActivity(i);
    return false;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);}}
```

Comment: Post your full stack trace from logcat.

Comment: it relly huge stack!!! @GabeSechan

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null pointer exception over here

```
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
String vlue = b.getString("val");
```

'b' is null. There are no intent extras. b.getString() throws and NPE exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: I tried to initialized value=" "; but no difference

Comment: the problem is that b (the bundle) is null